# Details with line number in the code for IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, exception, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to get more details of IndexOutOfBounds Exception details which includes line number in the program (basically which shows where the exception is occuring). I am getting the following exception but having hard time to find exactly where is this happening. Tried below:

```
try{
   //something
}catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException ex){
   log.debug(ex.getMessage+ex.toString); // and some others 
}
```

But i am just getting a message :

```
Index: 0, Size: 0java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

But not providing further details. i want to know where exactly the exception is happening. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `ex.printStackTrace()`

Comment: @VinceEmigh have tried that as well. But in log4j as String like:                           StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
     ex.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
     String exceptionDetails = sw.toString();. But that also just gave the same info.

Comment: Have you tried `log.error(Object, Throwable)`? (where `Object` is the message you want to attach to the error)

Comment: So you mean something like log.error("Exception details"+ex)? @VinceEmigh

Comment: Nope, the method accepts 2 arguments, so like: `log.error("An error has occured!", ex);`

Comment: @VinceEmigh JiriTousek also suggested teh same. I am trying that now and will post the result in couple of mins.

Comment: @VinceEmigh yes and no luck . It just display the message passed in the first argument but nothing after that.

Comment: Then you may have to fix up the appender you're using. If you want, you can manually print each line in the stack trace via: `Arrays.asList(ex.getStackTrace()).forEach(log::debug);`, although it would be better to dig into why log4j isnt handling the exception properly

Answer (score 0):

The "where" and "how we got there" is contained in the stack trace of the exception.

If that `log` is some standard logging framework, it will likely have a version with signature like `debug(String, Throwable)` that is capable of printing the stack trace / location info.

Otherwise, you'll have to either use `printStackTrace()` or access the stack trace element(s) you need through `getStackTrace()`.

Comment: And if it doesn't, you can call `ex.getStackTrace()` to obtain it and log it manually.

Comment: @azurefrog i have used getStackTrace but no further info is showing up . just the same info as posted in the question. But Could you please tell me more about what JiriTousek is talking about. I am using log4j for logging

Comment: @JiriTousek could you please provide further details on how to use it please? I am using log4j for logging here.

Comment: With log4j, use `log.debug("Error while doing foo to the bar", ex);`. If you still see nothing in the log, you might need to configure your Appender's format to print stack traces: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout